What's the reason for high voltage spikes with a W5500?
I'm using the original RPI4 power supply (5V) to power a board with a W5500 chip.
Basically there's some bypass caps at the input, then a 0.3 Ohm series resistor, and finally some 100uF ceramic caps, a big 200-1000uF electrolytic cap and a 100nF cap (caps are in parallel).
Now sometimes there are peak-2-peak spikes of up to 1V after the 0.3 Ohm series resistor.
The whole board draws ~150mA on average.
The caps are connected to different LDOs on the board. There is a big GND plane.
The peaks don't happen during startup (at least I haven't measured this) but during normal operation.
The peaks also happen if I remove the big electrolytic capacitor.




Lovely natural EFT waveform you found there!

Could also be an externally introduced EMI artefact. I would cross check this at another location/building.

I figured out that this could be due to the type of network cable being used. Maybe I've used a shielded network cable. The reason why this could be the source of the issue is: Sometimes the whole device will stop working for no apparent reason. And yesterday I did a test: shielded vs unshielded cable. When using the shielded one, the device would stop working within 2 hours - I could even reproduce this multiple times. Going with the unshielded cable I don't see this 1-2 hour failure.

If it's a shielded network cable issue, that isn't properly grounded, then I wonder why I could see these spikes at all with the oscilloscope which is earth referenced. So at least the scope should ground the device.. - on the other hand: maybe in this room there is no earth reference installed in the electrical wiring - so maybe the power sockets are not connected to earth.

Wrongly measuring? Adding inductive (and/or even conductive) EMI to the measured signal:

Creating an antenna between probe sense and ground like here can create spikes as seen in "Comparison of probe measurements taken with large ground loop (left) and the 'paperclip' method (right)" called picture in the link.

Proper measuring, e. g.:

Most DSO probes - after removing the tip - have a ground ring near the measuring pin - I did not find any good website, explaining this - just to e. g. wrap a blank wire around it to measure the ground next to the measuring point, like above picture.
In your case, you wrote about a 100 nF (ceramic - I assume) capacitor parallel to the 5 V. Such a big ceramic capacitor short cuts/kills  all (high) frequency spikes (electrolytic are only good for low! frequencies).
If you measure just on both pins of that 100 nF ceramic capacitor - like in above picture - you won´t have any spikes - or just very small ones, because the "small loop" is not zero and e. g. the coax cable of the DSO probe etc. is not perfect like in the theoretical world.
PS: A colleague 20 years ago had this problem too, he asked first for an expensive and better DSO than we had at that time. But it was above problem.
PS2: Nowadays (nearly) every power supply is a SMPS, your RPI4 power supply too, because input voltage is in the typical range 100 to 240V~ (old transformator based power supplies would work only for e. g. 220 - 240V~).

But mine takes several minutes to occur - it's not always there. On the left diagram it looks very regular.

These EMI signals can come from a SMPS, that could warm up, and then starts to produce the EMI signals after some minutes - or under certain load conditions it starts to swing... you say, when you remove the electrolytic capacitor, it starts too - contradictory electrolytic capacitors cannot dampen such signals - but if you remove it, you change the load of the SMPS and it could start to swing - constantly or intermittently. Where you connect the ground? Near to the measuring point? Please provide PCB layout and connection points.

Do you have a ground loop? The DSO is grounded, I assume - and perhaps the Raspberry is connected via a USB cable to a desktop PC - that is also grounded? Both yes and you can receive a lot of different EMI sources.

I don't use an SMPS, and the board being tested is powered by a RPI4 power supply which has only 2 connections to the wall plug (= not grounded).
There is a distance of 5cm between GND and testpoint.

@trevor: I edited the article as answer to your previous comment. Summary: (see PS2) your power supply is an SMPS, and if you measure accross the 100 nF ceramic capacitors 2 pins with "small loop" manner, you won't see any spikes - or negligible ones. 5cm = big loop.

It turned out that I also see spikes on different voltage rails on the board, some very rare, like every couple of hours, some more often.
It doesn't have anything to do with the way of measurement, because the spikes are also there when I measure with ground ring. I cannot measure every testpoint with a ground ring, but on 1 point I was able to, and that showed the same spikes.
Currently it seems that the cause might be ferrite beads on the board - not sure though.
Btw: the difference between the 2 measuring ways is: without ground ring I have more broadband high frequency noise.

If you measure with a ground ring (best across a ceramic capacitor) and you still have spikes --> is the probe cable's insulation against (too strong) electromagnetic waves bad? - or even the DSO internally is influenced by EMC - is it connected to the mains (with ground) - and is the measured device also connected (via a SMPS) to mains (with ground)? Then you could have a ground loop, that is very likely to pick up spikes from cables or "air".
